# Oracle aggregate Group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to build oracle sql query to do a GROUP BY only on column code_poste.
and get for each group all the columns with those creteria: min(START_DATE), max(END_DATE), max(INACTIF) + the rest of the column for that row.
[image]

[image]

Comment: cab you share with us some attempts of your? can you add as a text the column's name and the data useful to test?

Comment: Sample data as *text tables* rather than incomprehensible images would help.

Comment: Please review the appropriate way to ask a question on SO.

Comment: SELECT code_poste, description_m, code_poste_sup, code_rh_statut, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date), no_direction, no_division, no_service, no_section, code_secteur, code_site, description_f, nbr_hrs_jour, nbr_jrs_semaine, code_categorie, code_equipe, in_strategique, code_profile, code_profil_form, groupe_travail, poste_bidon, type_poste_entretien, dept, MAX(inactif) FROM table_poste GROUP BY code_poste

Comment: Have you done anything???

Comment: the result needed is with this query SELECT MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date), MAX(inactif) FROM table_poste GROUP BY code_poste. but my problem is how to complete the rest of the row with all other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get better help if you present a usable data set. I think from your description what you want is the entire row of data, but with the earliest and latest (start/end) dates for that group. To do this you would use analytic functions.

In the example below, testset is a generated set of random data. You would use your table in the select statement instead of testset. The key is the last select statement, it is returning all of the data in testset, along with the start and end dates as broken out by name and id.

I generated 999 rows so that we would have repeats of name/id so that you can see how the min/max work. I am only fetching the first 50 rows, that is enough to illustrate this works.

```
WITH
testset AS
    (SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.string( 'u', 1 )                          AS name
          , ROUND( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 10 ) )                   AS id
          , ROUND( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, 1000 ) )                 AS r100
          , TRUNC( SYSDATE + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( -100, 100 ) )     AS dateof
       FROM dba_objects
      WHERE ROWNUM < 1000)
SELECT name
     , id
     , r100
     , dateof
     , MIN( dateof ) OVER (PARTITION BY name, id)     AS start_date
     , MAX( dateof ) OVER (PARTITION BY name, id)     AS end_date
  FROM testset
  order by name, id, dateof
  fetch first 50 rows only;
```